# How to make size of TWRP smaller

Tags: android

I'm working on porting TWRP to my lenovo Tab 7 Essential. However, the built TWRP is too big for my recovery partition. (Of course I set recovery partition size in BoardConfig.mk)
`error: +/home/runner/work/Action-TWRP-Builder/Action-TWRP-Builder/workspace/out/target/product/TB7304F/recovery.img   too large (18214912 > [17301504 - 270336]) ninja: build stopped: command failed.`

My device's recovery partition size is 16777216 (=16384 block)

I heard of compressing ramdisk, however, I can not find how to do it.

Device tree is generated via twrp-dt-gen.

Can anyone help me to fit TWRP on my device?

I was expecting to successfully build it.

When I set recovery partition size bigger in BoardConfig.mk, build succedes, but I can't flash it.

Also, my device is quite strange that even when bootloader is unlocked, fastboot boot doesn't work and only fastboot flash works. So, I was not able to use `fastboot boot` method.

Comment: Fixed it by TW_EXCLUDE tags